# How to format XML file with CSS?

Tags: css, xml, parsing, nlp

I have an XML files with the Brown corpus in it. I want to create a simple CSS to make it more readable. For example I wish to highlight all the nouns in the sentence. This is a sample sentence from the XML file. < w > marks the words in it.

```
<s n="1">
    <w type="AT">The</w>
    <w type="NP" subtype="TL">Fulton</w>
    <w type="NN" subtype="TL">County</w>
    <w type="JJ" subtype="TL">Grand</w>
    <w type="NN" subtype="TL">Jury</w>
    <w type="VBD">said</w>
    <w type="NR">Friday</w>
    <w type="AT">an</w>
    <w type="NN">investigation</w>
    <w type="IN">of</w>
    <w type="NPg">Atlanta's</w>
    <w type="JJ">recent</w>
    <w type="NN">primary</w>
    <w type="NN">election</w>
    <w type="VBD">produced</w>
    <c type="pct">``</c>
    <w type="AT">no</w>
    <w type="NN">evidence</w>
    <c type="pct">''</c>
    <w type="CS">that</w>
    <w type="DTI">any</w>
    <w type="NNS">irregularities</w>
    <w type="VBD">took</w>
    <w type="NN">place</w>
    <c type="pct">.</c>
</s>
```

I wish to highlight all words that have the type="NN" and type="NNS"
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style it like any other document if you include the reference to the CSS file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css"?>
... rest of document here...
```

[Taken from the w3 documentation.](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html)

**EDIT**

If you wish to style by attribute, CSS has this capability:

```
*[type="NNS"] {
    color:red;
}
```

or if you wanted to be specific to the tag as well:

```
w[type="NNS"] {
    color:red;
}
```

[Here is a bit more documentation on CSS using attribute selectors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: I am aware of that, I just do not know how to get the specific needed elements from the XML (like <w type="NN">)

Comment: edited my answer to display applying CSS using attribute selectors.